# How to workaround this Excel VBA issue with regards to code prioritization?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a deactivate event on one of my worksheet that activates this code:

```
Dim Total_rows_DTR As Long
Dim Total_rows_PU As Long
Dim Total_rows_PR As Long
Dim Total_rows_PTS As Long
Dim Total_Columns4 As Long
Dim Total_rows_EX4 As Long
Dim Sum As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim w As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim e As Long
Dim q As Long

Total_rows_DTR = Workbooks("Revised-Payroll (VBA Copy).xlsm").Worksheets("DTR").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_PU = Workbooks("Revised-Payroll (VBA Copy).xlsm").Worksheets("Payroll Update").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_PR = Workbooks("Revised-Payroll (VBA Copy).xlsm").Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To Total_rows_PU
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Payroll Tables and Settings").Range("D2:D1048576"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 1), Worksheets("Payroll Tables and Settings").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)) <> Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 5) _
    And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 5)) = False Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Payroll Tables and Settings").Range("D2:D1048576"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 1), Worksheets("Payroll Tables and Settings").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)) = "Extra" Then
            For h = 3 To Total_Columns4
                If Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(1, h) = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 1) Then
                    For q = 2 To Total_rows_EX4
                        If Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, 2) < Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 2) And IsFormula(Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h)) = True Then
                            Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h).Copy
                            Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                            :=False, Transpose:=False
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, 2) >= Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 2) And Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, 1) >= Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 2) Then
                            Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h).Clear
                        ElseIf Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, 2) >= Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 2) And Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, 1) < Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 2) Then
                            Sum = 0
                            For e = 2 To Total_rows_DTR
                                If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(e, 3) >= Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, 1) And Worksheets("DTR").Cells(e, 3) < Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 2) And Worksheets("DTR").Cells(e, 2) = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 1) Then
                                    Sum = Sum + Worksheets("DTR").Cells(e, 28)
                                End If
                            Next e
                            If Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h) <> Sum And IsFormula(Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h)) = True Then
                                Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h) = Worksheets("Payroll - Extra").Cells(q, h) + Worksheets("DTR").Cells(e, 28)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next q
                End If
            Next h
        End If
        For w = 2 To Total_rows_PTS
            If Worksheets("Payroll Tables and Settings").Cells(w, 1) = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 1) Then
                Worksheets("Payroll Tables and Settings").Cells(w, 4) = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Cells(j, 5)
            End If
        Next w   
    End If
Next j
```

However, my problem is that when I click another worksheet, the deactivate event runs, and keeps switching from the worksheet I clicked on and with the worksheet that is written in the code, which is `Worksheets("Payroll - Extra")`. This is a problem because every time the worksheet switches the events of the worksheet I clicked on may also trigger. Such example is when I click a worksheet with an activate or deactivate event. This caused my code to error at some point. How do I get by this?

Below is a flowchart in attempt to make it more clear with regards to the problem:
[image: Flowchart]

Comment: There is also an error where several lines should read  Application.WorksheetFunction.IsFormula

Comment: I believe there is also an IsFormula function within VBE? It has worked for me with no issue. If there was no built in function it would have error-ed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. Gave error for me in 2016.

Comment: @QHarr - seems to be an Office365 addition.

Comment: So you are using the Workbook sheet deactivate event? Use the sheet event instead or add an If to your workbook code to specify sheet(s).

Comment: I'm referring to worksheet deactivate events. So it goes like this: Current sheet -> Click on another sheet -> Deactivate event of current sheet runs -> The current sheet code will open `Worksheets("Payroll - Extra")` -> If the clicked sheet is not `Worksheets("Payroll - Extra")` and has an event it may activate -> Go back to the clicked sheet -> Repeat

Comment: It's impossible to answer properly with the vague information you have given. You just have to make sure you only activate the code when the appropriate sheet(s) is activated or deactivated.

Comment: It is quite hard to explain. I will add a flowchart in the main post

Comment: It would help to show exactly how the code is triggered. Also, your code would be much easier to read and maintain if you used some variables for your worksheets and other items.  There's a large amount of repetition here.

Comment: I did think about that although since it's a worksheet event it's too much code. It'll flood the entire page. I'll add in my variable declarations. The issue is that the effect of the code activation as a whole instead of specifically in the code which makes it hard to explain clearly

Comment: For instance, when I press a worksheet with a deactivate event it will have a different effect than when I press a worksheet with a worksheet change event or a worksheet with no event activations

Comment: Any code which runs as the result of an activate/deactivate event shouldn't be performing any worksheet selections itself (or if it does, it should first suspend event handling)

Comment: How to suspend event handling though? That may work

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` but you must be sure to set it back to True when done or none of your events will fire.

Comment: Thanks I believe this will work unless the current event procedure being run gets halted altogether when that line activates.

Comment: `EnableEvents` doesn't affect running code - only subsequent events

Comment: Great I believe it would work. Thanks